# Check if X509Certificate2 will work with http/2 in Google Chrome an Mozilla Firefox

Tags: encryption, .net-core, http2, x509certificate2, kestrel-http-server

we are running a Dotnet Core 3.0 application that provides a web api via Kestrel. By default Kestrel has set available protocols to `Protocols.Http1AndHttp2`.

On one of our testmachines it turned out that http/2 does not work in combination with Google Chrome (77.0.3865.90). The browser displays an error with `ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY` message. The fallback to http1 does not work in this case because the browser does support http/2 in general. 
Microsoft Edge btw. **does** support requesting the same endpoint via http/2.

I tested the certificate on my develop machine and it turns out that this works as expected. So it does not seem to be a problem with the certificate itself rather than the server hosting the application. My local machine is running Windows 10 Pro (1903). The server is running Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter (6.3.9600).

The application will be hosted at our customers servers as a self contained package and *we will not have an impact* on what servers the api will be running.

Instead of disabling http/2 completely, we would like to check if all browsers will accept the provided certificate in combination of http/2. I'm not sure how to find this out on server side. To us it seems to be some kind of problem regarding to the provided cipher suites but I got no idea on how to check the compatibility on server side.

Does anyone have an idea on how to check the compatibility?

Answer (score 4):

It’s not the certificate it’s the cipher suites.

Run your site through this tool: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ (or download and use https://testssl.sh if not publicly available, internal site) and you’ll see the cipher suites configured.

HTTP/2 blacklists older ciphers and Chrome won’t use HTTP/2 if those are configured. The list is here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#appendix-A but basically you probably should be using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for Chrome.

This post tells you how to change them for IIS: https://medium.com/@rootsecdev/configuring-secure-cipher-suites-in-windows-server-2019-iis-7d1ff1ffe5ea

Comment: Thank you, Barry.
Knowing that this is a problem regarding to the cipher suites is a big step now. As the application is running via Kestrel, configuring IIS will not solve the problem. Apart from that, the software is running on our customer's servers so that we do not have an impact on the global cipher suites.
I am looking for a way now to identify the provided cipher suites and check them against the blacklist. The aim is to disable HTTP/2 if there are blacklisted suites available.
Any idea on this? I'm already using BouncyCastle in my project but could not find anything helpful.